# Jsoup filter out only some tags from html to text

Tags: html, jsoup, java

can any master of jsoup tell me some suggestions to filter html to text/string? I've tried calling text() of Document. But all tags/elements will be filtered. My aim is to filter some specified tags.

i.e: I've html text like:

```
<div>hello<p>world</div>,<table><tr><td>xxx</td></tr>
```

to get result:

```
<div>hello<p>world</div>,xxx
```

which has filtered  tags.

Comment: To clarify: You want to get the html out but without some of the tags?

Comment: @selig yes you are right. Not all tags should be removed, just some what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this right now but I think you want to write a recursive function that steps through the tree and prints each node based on a condition. The following is an example of what it might look like but I expect that you will have to modify it to suit your needs more precisely.

```
Document doc = JSoup.parse(page_text);
recursive_print(doc.head());
recursive_print(doc.body());

...

private static Set<String> ignore = new HashSet<String>(){{
  add("table");
  ...
}};
public static void recursive_print(Element el){
   if(!ignore.contains(el.className()))
     System.out.println(el.html());
   for(Element child : el.children())
     recursive_print(child);
}
```

Comment: That's what I want. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Whitelist` to achieve this goal. For example:

`Whitelist whiteList = new Whitelist();

 whiteList.addTags("div", "p", "td");`

It means that all other tags will be removed.