# How to avoid surrounding html head tags in Jsoup parse

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

Using Jsoup i try to parse the given html content. After Jsoup.parse() the html output append html, head and body tag to the input. I just want to ignore these.

**Sample Input:**

```
<p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>
```

Java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HTMLParse {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try{
            File input = new File("/ab.html");
            String html = FileUtils.readFileToString(input, null);

            Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
            doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
            System.out.println(doc.html());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual output:**

```
<html><head></head><body><p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>
    </body></html>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>
```

Please help.

Comment: This should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492396/jsoup-filter-out-only-some-tags-from-html-to-text

Comment: @Jitendra I want property like this. http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/faq.html#fragments

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### The cause:

`parseBodyFragment()` as well as all other `parse()`-methods use a ***HTML parser*** by *default*. And those add *always* the HTML-Shell (`<html>…</html>`, `<head>…</head>` etc.).

#### The Solution:

Just don't use a HTML-parser, use a ***XML-parser instead*** ;-)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

Replace that single line and your problem is solved.

#### Example:

```
final String html = "<p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>";

Document docHtml = Jsoup.parse(html);
Document docXml = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

System.out.println("******* HTML *******\n" + docHtml);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("*******  XML *******\n" + docXml);
```

**Output:**

```
******* HTML *******
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>
 </body>
</html>

*******  XML *******
<p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>
```

Comment: A potential downside of that is you're not getting any of the HTML tidying - the XML parser doesn't care about HTML5 structure and lets content through as-is. If you want tidied body HTML, use `Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html).body();`

Comment: This only works if your html is xml. Unfortunately, if you have things like img tags that aren't terminated, the xml parser will assume the following tags are inside.

Comment: I can understand if you're using XML already, but relying on XML just for this use case is imo not a great idea

Answer (score 15):

To get the expected output it would actually be:

```
final String html = "<p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try using the XML parser, but this doesn't always work because HTML is not always XML; it often has unterminated tags like `<img>` and `<br>`. It's better to stick with the HTML parser. You can rely on there being `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags and they are easy to discard. Just get your fragment of HTML by selecting the body tag and ask for its HTML.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
        doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
        System.out.println(doc.select("body").html());
```

Comment: upvoted for warning about xml parser. i almost did that despite my usecase for jsoup being to correct images. Also wanted to comment .html() on the body element is the inner html only. It does not include the surrounding body tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jsoup.parse also with HTML parser. All you need to do is to strip the `html` and `body` wrappers away.

This can be done by selecting the `body` element and **unwrapping** it:

```
String input = "<p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>";
Node content = Jsoup.parse(input).body().unwrap();
System.out.println(content.html());
```

By `body()` you select `body` element and by `unwrap()` you remove body and only content remains.

So output is:

```
<p><b>This <i>is</i></b> <i>my sentence</i> of text.</p>
```