# jsoup mistakes a token as an HTML tag

Tags: jsoup

I've got an html fragment as follows:

```
<span class=#article-title#>About《About<SomeChineseChars》Blabla</span>
```

*sorry here I use latin chars since the editor does not allow to type Chinese chars*

when I try to extract text out of this element using

```
doc.select(".article-title").text();
```

I will finally have the below as the result:

```
About《About》Blabla
```

after debugging the programming, finding that

```
<SomeChineseChars>
```

was treated as an HTML tag and JSoup close the tag automatically as follows

```
<SomeChineseChars></SomeChineseChars>
```

So, if there is anyway to avoid this from happening, or if this is a BUG?

-=-=-= UPDATE =-=-=-

after dom is built and then check the parsed html, the output is

[I cannot post img, so plz click me to view it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdJ5D.png)

Thanks a lot,
Ben

Comment: try this, `String html = Jsoup.connect(url).get().outerHtml();Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html).body();`

Comment: @Abhilash didn't work :(

Comment: try this, `String html = Jsoup.connect(url).get().outerHtml(); Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181942/8329042)

Comment: thanks, but it still didnot work, actually, after .outerHtml() the dom tree has already been built and mean time the token was parsed as an HTML tag.

Comment: Connection.Response resp = 
    Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
    String html = resp.body();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html,url, Parser.xmlParser());    I tried this way to get the original html string and then gave it a try with  your method, but it let me down again, seems like the parser is the point

Comment: can you post the actual html fragment ?

Comment: @Abhilash sure, but the the html contains Chinese words so that the editor doesn't let me pass, here is the link : http://gk.tj.gov.cn/gkml/00012525X/200804/t20080425_49468.shtml  and you may find the article title contains <Some Chinese words>

Comment: I don't see any issue with Jsoup. I am able to get the text. Used Selenium to wait for the page to load and parsed the PageSource using Jsoup.

Comment: @Abhilash plz use   doc.select("#span_docTitle").text() and then you will see

Comment: @Abhilash btw, which version were you using ? mine is 1.11.2

Comment: please check the answer and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made up a solution by hacking into the JSoup as following:

1. create a new package named org.jsoup.parser;
2. customize a HtmlTreeBuilder

   ```
   public class TroilaHtmlTreeBuilder extends HtmlTreeBuilder {

   private String zh = "[\\u4e00-\\u9fa5]+";

   public TroilaHtmlTreeBuilder() {
   }

   @Override
   Element insert(Token.StartTag startTag) {
       if (startTag.tagName.matches(zh)) {
           Token.Character ch = new Token.Character();
           ch.data(startTag.toString());
           insert(ch);
           return null;
       }
       return super.insert(startTag);
   }

   public Document parse(Reader input, String baseUri) {
       return super.parse(input, baseUri, ParseErrorList.noTracking(), this.defaultSettings());
   }

   }
   ```

I don't think this is a good way to solve the problem, so let me know if you have any better idea.

BTW: many thanks to @Abhilash for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://gk.tj.gov.cn/gkml/00012525X/200804/t20080425_49468.shtml")
            .timeout(180 * 1000).get();
    String html = doc.outerHtml().replaceAll("<天津市企业实行商务卡结算财务管理暂行办法>", "&lt;天津市企业实行商务卡结算财务管理暂行办法&gt;");;
    doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    System.out.println(doc.select("#span_docTitle").text());
```

Output:

```
转发《关于印发 <天津市企业实行商务卡结算财务管理暂行办法> 的通知》的通知
```

Comment: Abhilash, thanks so much, but I don't see where JSoup is in, actually I tried in Chrome console with jquery using the same selector it also worked.  Could you please try it just using bare JSoup if you have time , thanks again.

Comment: I updated the post with an image link that you may want to see

Comment: @Ben, if this is the only tag that is causing issues, then the simplest way is to escape it manually.

Comment: I hoped so, but it didn't take long before I found more :(, anyway thanks very very much. I solved the issue by customizing the tree builder it now it works, I tried with different version by upgrading/downgrading JSoup but no luck, I think it is a BUG.