# I cannot open a link with jsoup

Tags: java, eclipse, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get the descriptions of grants from the Carnegie Foundation and to do so, I need to open links to get the Document. This works on browsers, but not when I use JSoup.connect(url).get() on Eclipse. My code works with other links but not these type specifically. Is there a work-around?
One of the links is "https://www.carnegie.org/grants/grants-database/grant/680882743.0/".

```
try {           
        currentDoc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("URL cannot be reached");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

Comment: Which error do you get?  Please print full stacktrace of the `IOException` before constructing the runtime exception.  You may need just to wrap IOException: `throw new RuntimeException("URL cannot be reached: " + url, e);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you are trying to access is returning a JSON document that contains HTML content. This is different from regular pages that return a HTML document. `Jsoup.connect` expects a HTML document.

In order to handle this scenario you need to:

1. [Retrieve the JSON document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java)
2. Extract the HTML content from the `result` JSON property
3. Parse the HTML content using [`Jsoup.parse`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse(java.lang.String))

You may want to [treat the HTML content as a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173769/how-to-avoid-surrounding-html-head-tags-in-jsoup-parse), rather than a document by using `Jsoup.parse(htmlContent, "", Parser.xmlParser())`.

If you're traversing a website and need to write code that can handle both HTML and JSON documents, I suggest the following workflow:

1. Use `URLConnection` to retrieve the data.
2. Check the `content-type` header in the response.
3. If the Content Type is `application/json`, extract the HTML content from the `result` property in the response payload or else assume the entire response payload is HTML.
4. Parse the result from the previous step using `Jsoup.parse`

Note that this code assumes that every JSON document has a property called `result` with the HTML content. This may be enough for your specific use case, but is definitely not a valid assumption for all JSON documents out there.